# File naming convention definition in Sonar

Tags: java, sonarqube, checkstyle

I have a java project with a couple of layers. I want to define a rules for file naming convention in Sonar server, e.g. each file in package `app.name.dao` to have name like `ClassNameDAO.java`.

Is this possible with some of the tools which Sonar is using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any other option than creating a dedicated Checkstyle rule (http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/writingchecks.html) which would be embedded into your own Sonar plugin.

Here is an example of such Sonar plugin defining a simple Checkstyle rule : https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/plugins/sonar-checkstyle-extension-plugin